# How to Pass Data/Variables From a POST Route to a GET Route in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, post, get

I'm working on an ecommerce website that lets you order a product and lets you fill out customer information (name, email, card-info, etc.) in a form before paying. When they fill the form out and click "pay", it sends a POST request where the actual charging takes place.

```
router.post("/pay", async (req, res) => {
    // Charging Code Here
            ...
    // Charging Code Here

    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var number = req.body.number;
});
```

After the charging, I want to extract the info from the form, as done above, and send a GET request where I can render a page where I can display the customer information on the new page using the variables in the POST route.

```
router.get("/confirmation", function(req, res, next) {
        res.render("confirmation.ejs", { name:name, email:email, number:number });
});
```

With all that being said, how can I take the name, email, and number variables from the POST route and use it in the GET route? I don't want to store the customer info in a database as I want everyone to place an order without making some sort of account.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is passing the variables as request in GET method, like:

```
router.get("/confirmation/:name/:email/:number", function(req, res, next) {
        res.render("confirmation.ejs", { name:req.name, email:req.email, number:req.number });
});
```